# How to link to view file in controller by click view name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

A springboot web project,work by idea . in the controller code,I want to  click "manage/operate/createCluster"  ,then  the idea will open the /web-inf/jsp/manage/operate/createCluster.jsp file.

How to achieve or what information can be referenced?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "createCluster", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doClusterList(HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("activeMenuId","createCluster");
    return new ModelAndView("manage/operate/createCluster");
}
```

Comment: can you explain what problem arises

Answer (score 0):

If you want just affiche a view without any data to populate you can add a view controller in Your WebMvc config class like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implement WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addViewController("/manage/operate/createCluster").setViewName("manage/operate/createCluster");
}
```

}

If you want to send data in your view as your example you must just send the view name as String:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "createCluster", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doClusterList(HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
model.addAttribute("activeMenuId","createCluster");
return "manage/operate/createCluster";
```

}

You should add config of your view Resolver for both cases :

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
   InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
   resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
   return resolver;
 }
```